# Numeros vizinhos em um Lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, python-requests

Olá alguém pode me ajudar com um exercício? Tenho uma Lista, Não Ordenada, e preciso percorrer uma lista, e retornar apenas os números vizinhos que são maiores que os elementos a direita e esquerda. O primeiro é último elemento da lista não serão considerados por não terem um dos números vizinhos. O resultado final deve ser os números: 916, 638 e 894.
Lista 705,693,593,646,916,637,638,176,894,370

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta?cb=1

Answer (score -2):

Ola, Alexandre! Boa tarde.

Consegui realizar da seguinte forma:

```
lista = [705, 693, 593, 646, 916, 637, 638, 176, 894, 370]


for i, numero in enumerate(lista):
    if i == 0 or i == len(lista)-1:
        pass
    else:
        if numero > lista[i+1] and numero > lista[i-1]:
            print(numero)
```

Deve haver formas mais simples, mas essa funcionou.

Comment: Arthur obrigado pela ajuda, confesso que não conhecia a função enumerate. Agora é estudar mais, pois fiquei quase dois dias quebrando a cabeça e só consegui chegar em valores booleanos